# Pydantic and "constructors"

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm new to Pydantic and trying to understand how/if I can create a new class instance.   I've read through the Pydantic documentation and can't find an example doing anything similar.

My python code (prior to Pydantic) looks like:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, id):
        db_result = get_db_content(id)    #lookup id in a database and return a result
        self.name = db_result['name']      
        self.birth_year = db_result['birth_year']

p1 = Person(1234)
print(p1.name)
```

What would the corresponding code in Pydantic look like if I want to create a Person instance
based on an id?  Also, is it possible with Pydantic to have multiple constructors for the same
class.    For example:

```
p1 = Person(1234)
p2 = Person("Jane Doe")
```

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure if this is the most "pydantic" way to do things, but one approach to solving this problem is to use `classmethods`.

```
class Person(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    birth_year: int

    @classmethod
    def from_id(cls, id: int) -> "Person":
        db_result = get_db_content(id)    #lookup id in a database and return a result
        return cls(**db_result)

p1 = Person.from_id(1234)
print(p1.name)
```

Answer (score 10):

You could use a standard __init__ for this:

```
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel

def get_db_content(id):
    return {
        'name': f'hello {id}',
        'birth_year': 2010,
    }

class Person(BaseModel):
    id: str
    name: Optional[str]
    birth_year: Optional[int]
    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        super().__init__(*a, **kw)
        db_result = get_db_content(self.id)
        self.name = db_result['name']      
        self.birth_year = db_result['birth_year']

person = Person(id='15')
print(person.dict())
# {'id': '15', 'name': 'hello 15', 'birth_year': 2010}
```

Although, personally I wouldn't do that. Pydantic classes are meant to be used as parsers/validators, not as fully functional object entities. Calling DB methods from a class like this directly couples your class to the db code and makes testing more difficult.

I would do this instead:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

def get_db_content(id):
    return {
        'name': f'hello {id}',
        'birth_year': 2010,
    }

class Person(BaseModel):
    id: str
    name: str
    birth_year: int

person = Person(id='15', **get_db_content('15'))
print(person.dict())
# {'id': '15', 'name': 'hello 15', 'birth_year': 2010}
```

NB: the code examples should be self-contained and work as-is.

edit: using standard dunder constructor instead of @root_validator

Comment: The signature `def __init__(self, *a, **kw)` is horrible from a type annotation perspective and defeats pydantic's `init_typed = True` feature.

Comment: @bluenote10 agreed. i didn't annotate it properly (let's say for brevity :) ), but that's another reason for not putting db calls inside `__init__` - so you don't have to worry about the inheritance chain

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really possible at the moment. You'll have to create the person with something like `Person(get_db_content())`.

In future you'll be able to have computed fields and context that would allow this.

Comment: Hi. Is there any chance that it got better now? I couldn't find anything about computed fields and context in the docs.

Comment: Not yet, I think there might be an open pull request, but I don't have time to review it right now.

Answer (score 2):

One pattern you might consider is using a 'collection' class for your pydantic model.

Your model can (should) just be a data store / validator as folks have mentioned.  And your collection class can act as your interface to the DB for fetching records, groups of records, performing finds, etc.. and returning your model objects, or lists of model objects.

Example pydantic class:

```
class Person(BaseModel):
    id: str
    name: Optional[str]
    birth_year: Optional[int]
```

Collection Class:

```
class PersonCollection:
    def __init__(self, db: pymongo.database.Database):
        self.collection = db.person_collection

    def find_people(self, criteria: dict) -> List[Person]:
        person_list: List[Person] = list()
        for person_data in self.collection.find(criteria):
            person_list.append(Person(**person_data))
        return person_list
    
     def save_person(self, person: Person):
        key = {"id": person.id}
        self.collection.update_one(
            filter=key,
            update={"$set": person.dict()},
            upsert=True
         )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly more robust version of ierdna's first answer:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

def get_db_content(id):
    return {
        'name': f'ID: {id}',
        'birth_year': 2022
    }

class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    birth_year: int

    def __init__(self, id=None, **kwargs):
        if id is not None:
            # Look up the id from the database
            db_result = get_db_content(id)    
            kwargs.update(db_result)

        super().__init__(**kwargs)

p1 = Person(1234)
# Output: Person(name='ID 1234', birth_year=2022)

p2 = Person(name="Jack", birth_year=2020)
# Output: Person(name='Jack', birth_year=2020)
```

This has the benefit that if `id` is specified, constructor fetches from the database and if not, then the item is formed directly from given keyword arguments. This also supports setting the model as immutable as we don't set the attributes ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the previous answers and just wanted to share an additional solution, which I think addresses all the requirements from the initial question. The idea is to register additional constructors via `model_validator` and a custom decorator to map the right constructor based on the keyword arguments passed by the user.

It essentially extends the answer by @James P to handle all alternative init methods in `__init__` and allow for an arbitrary number of those:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator
import inspect

def get_db_content(id):
    if id == 1234:
        return {"name": "Luke Skywalker", "birth_year": 1978}

    raise ValueError(f"Id {id} Not found")


def alternative_init(func):
    """Alternative init decorator"""
 
    arguments = set(inspect.signature(func).parameters)
    arguments.remove("cls")

    def wrapper(cls, values, handler):
        """Wrapper"""
        keys = set(values)
        valid_arguments = keys.intersection(arguments)
        valid_fields = keys.intersection(cls.model_fields)

        # The largest common subset of keys is used infer the intendend constructor
        if len(valid_arguments) > len(valid_fields):
            instance = func(cls, **values)
            values = instance.model_dump()

        return handler(values)

    return model_validator(mode="wrap")(wrapper)


class Person(BaseModel):
    """Person"""
    name: str
    birth_year: int

    @alternative_init
    def from_id(cls, id):
        db_result = get_db_content(id)
        return cls(**db_result)
    
    @alternative_init
    def from_other_id(cls, other_id):
        db_result = get_db_content(other_id)
        return cls(**db_result)


p1 = Person(id=1234)
print(p1.name, p1.birth_year)

p1 = Person(name="Darth Vader", birth_year=1999)
print(p1.name, p1.birth_year)

p1 = Person(other_id=1234)
print(p1.name, p1.birth_year)
```

Which prints:

```
Luke Skywalker 1978
Darth Vader 1999
Luke Skywalker 1978
```

However it is not the most efficient solutions as it goes through one additional model validation for the alternative inits. I would also only recommend it when used with multiple models. To justify the additional code required for the decorator. Still the final use and implementation is quite elegant I think and corresponds to the intended behavior of the initial question. Except for the keyword only handling, but this is imposed by Pydantic.

I hope this helps!