# Initializing Class Attributes With Pydantic and Pandera

Tags: python, initialization, instantiation, pydantic, pandera

I'm new to Pydantic and Pandera, and need some help with class instantiation and initialization.

I have the following code in one file, `sim.py`:

```
import pandera as pa
from pydantic import BaseModel
from datetime import datetime

class ScheduleDF(pa.SchemaModel):
    person_id: Series[int] = pa.Field(ge=0, coerce=True)
    shift_id: Series[int] = pa.Field(ge=0, coerce=True)
    start_time: Series[datetime]
    end_time: Series[datetime]

class Schedule(BaseModel):
    schedule_df: DataFrame[ScheduleDF]
    events_df: DataFrame[EventsDF]

    @pa.check_types
    def initialize_from_df(self, schedule_df: DataFrame[ScheduleDF]):
        self.schedule_df = schedule_df
```

and the following code in another file, `sim_test.py`:

```
from sim import ScheduleDF, Schedule

def test_schedule():
    y = 2022
    m = 9
    d = 1

    schedule_df = DataFrame[ScheduleDF](
        {'person_id': [1, 2], 'shift_id': [10, 20],
         'start_time': [datetime(y, m, d, 0, 0, 1), datetime(y, m, d, 0, 0, 5)],
         'end_time': [datetime(y, m, d, 0, 0, 3), datetime(y, m, d, 0, 0, 6)]
        }
    )
    sample_schedule = Schedule()
    sample_schedule.initialize_from_df(schedule_df)

test_schedule()
```

When I run `sim_testing.py`, I get the following error:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for Schedule
schedule_df
field required (type=value_error.missing)
events_df
field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

I can see why the `events_df` is missing - I don't initialize it inside of `test_schedule()`. However, it seems that I've initialized the `schedule_df`.

I tried adding `@classmethod` above the `@pa.check_types` decorator for `initialize_from_df()` and changing `self` in that function to `cls` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61789002/pydantic-and-constructors) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66932842/constructor-and-pydantic), but it gave me those same errors still. It seems to be a Pydantic issue and not a Pandera issue.

I would appreciate some help figuring out what's going on and how I can rectify it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Schedule` class, you defined two mandatory fields, `schedule_df` and `event_df`.

```py
class Schedule(BaseModel):
    schedule_df: DataFrame[ScheduleDF]
    events_df: DataFrame[EventsDF]
```

So, when you try to instantiate it with `sample_schedule = Schedule()`, it will necessarily fail as you don't provide any value for those two mandatory fields.

Basically, you have two ways forward:

1. Pass instances of `ScheduleDF` and `EventsDF` when instantiating, like that (note: you forgot to give us the definition of the `EventsDF` class, so I'm just making one up):

```py
schedule_df = DataFrame[ScheduleDF](
    {
        'person_id': [1, 2],
        'shift_id': [10, 20],
        'start_time': [datetime(y, m, d, 0, 0, 1), datetime(y, m, d, 0, 0, 5)],
        'end_time': [datetime(y, m, d, 0, 0, 3), datetime(y, m, d, 0, 0, 6)]
    }
)

events_df = DataFrame[EventsDF](
    {
        'event_id': [1],
        'start_time': [datetime(y, m, d, 0, 0, 3)],
        'end_time': [datetime(y, m, d, 0, 0, 4)]
    }
)

sample_schedule = Schedule(schedule_df=schedule_df, events_df=events_df)
```

2. Or, if you really want to assign values to `schedule_df` and `events_df` afterwards, make them optional in the class definition:

```py
from typing import Optional


class Schedule(BaseModel):
    schedule_df: Optional[DataFrame[ScheduleDF]]
    events_df: Optional[DataFrame[EventsDF]]
```

With that, calling `sample_schedule = Schedule()` will work, and `sample_schedule` will basically contain `schedule_df=None events_df=None`.